# MEDIA QUERY For orientation: landscape but not desktop. how?

Tags: css, angular, scss-lint

Here it will not contain it on the tablet because I am testing a tablet with a mouse on my computer:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px), (not: pointer) and (orientation: landscape)
```

And here it will also contain a desktop.

```
@media (max-width: 1024px), (orientation: landscape)
```

so How can I solve it ?
Thanks

Comment: Solve what, exactly? Are you trying to identify devices _types_? If so, what for?

Comment: @CBroe yes, I want to define tablet device on orientation: landscape. not potrait and not desktop

Comment: You can combine height and width parameters in the media query

Comment: @SigurdMazanti what height is the min for desktop and will fit mobile and tablet?

Comment: @bobhabanai if you open Chrome's DevTools you can choose a lot of device layouts. I can't give you any specific dimensions as I'm not 100% sure sorry. Example: https://gyazo.com/27e35f4417d8443882c511bd8f99d19d